# how can i run a .vp6 file on ubuntu?

Tags: games, file-format, video-conversion, mkv

Some time ago I installed a video game (need for speed most wanted) on my pc with ubuntu 22.04.1lts operating system. The problem was that the cinematics weren't working for me, and over time I found out that they were in a type of .vp6 format, which I don't know. Now just out of curiosity I would like to know if there is any way to play those files, or make them work correctly in the game. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can play them in the VLC Media Player.

[VP6 is a video format created by On2](https://wiki.videolan.org/VP6/)

You may need FFMPEG installed on your system as the codec to support the file format.

Comment: In OP said play them in the game there for this is not an answer.

Comment: @David I'd imagine installing a supporting codec to the system would help